# Prevent mail delivery errors from forwarded address for spam

Tags: email, gmail, procmail

I forward my email from a linux server (running exim) to my gmail account using procmail.  Frequently I get "Mail delivery failed" errors from spam messages sent to me, where the error is an SMTP rejection from gmail due to a potential security issue.  I guess that exim/procmail is configured to inform me (rather than the original sender of the email) about SMTP errors coming from addresses that I forward my mail to, since in general that may indicate a problem with my forwarding configuration.  However, in this case, the error is not my problem, but that of the original sender.  How can I configure exim/procmail not to send me these messages?

Answer (score 1):

With some hesitation, I would consider the `Auto-Submitted:` header standardized in [RFC3834](http://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc3834) which allows you to suppress bounce messages for automatically generated email. As such, it's not really intended to be used on forwarded messages, but it's worth a shot.

You would add that to the forwarded message something like this:

```
:0
| formail -I "Auto-Submitted: forwarded" \
  | $SENDMAIL -oi -f '' yourinbox@gmail.example.com
```

The `forwarded` value is not standardized, but the way I read the spec, any value other than "no" should suppress bounces.

I also threw in the `-f ''` option as a fallback; if it works, it could be useful by its own, as many mail servers will not generate bounces for messages which have an empty envelope sender.  However, not all sites allow you to control this.

Comment: Thanks!  I haven't tried it yet, but I'm not sure that this will be quite the right fix, since RFC3834 specifically says that it's not about delivery status notifications, which are described instead in [RFC3461](http://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc3461).  If I'm reading the emails correctly, gmail is not _bouncing_ exactly, but refusing the messages at the SMTP level, which causes _my_ mail server to issue a DSN.

Comment: Then the `-f ''` option to Sendmail may be all you need.